# How to call component from index.html in a hyperlink in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-router

```html
<li><a [router-link]="['/contact']"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
```

I have a navbar present in index.html in which there is a Contact tab.
I want to call the Contact component present in my 'app' folder inside the that tab. Below is my syntax that I tried but not working....

My Angular CLI version is 1.4.10

Comment: Are you using Angular 4, or AngularJS 1.4? Give a [mcve] that shows how this link is being used.

Comment: Angular 4 and the Angular/cli version is 1.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your app route, personally I do it in the app.module.ts but you can do it in another file and then import it in your app.module.ts

```
import ...
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ContactComponent } from 'path of component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {path: 'contact', component: contactComponent}
] 

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      ...,
      ContactComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your navbar, `<li><a routerLink="contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>`

Be careful to use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` instead of `<app-yourAppName></app-yourAppName>` to call your principal component in `app.component.html`, with router-outlet Angular will call the component that you want by clicking on router-link.

Comment: I'd registered everything in app.module.ts but still cant call  component from main index.html

Comment: Can you show me a screen of `app.module.ts`, `app.module.html` and if it's not in this last one, your file with the navbar please ?

Answer (score 1):

@Alexis

```js
//app.module.ts file
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RouterModule,Route} from '@angular/router';
//importing components
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
//creating URLs for components
const routelist:Route[]=[
  {path:'contact', component:ContactComponent},
]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, ContactComponent//Components registered.
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routelist)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```html
<!--Main index.html file outside app folder-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Heroes</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="pic" height="70" width="90">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a router-link="contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <footer><strong>|| <i class="fas fa-copyright"></i> BAREFACED Bear ||</strong></footer>
</body>
</html>


<!--app.component.html file-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Routes module takes an 's', try it and tell me if it works

Comment: sorry nothing changed

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake, write `routerLink` instead of `router-link`

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen my answer in which I told you to try by changing `router-link` in `routerLink` ? It Works ?